# Understanding receiveTimeout in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to understand "receiveTimeout" binding property in WCF by following code:

Server side:

```
ServiceHost serviceHostForStrong = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8887/Service"));
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        basicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8887/Service/");
        ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint =
            new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IServiceContract)),
                basicHttpBinding,
                endpointAddress);
        serviceHostForStrong.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);
        serviceHostForStrong.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service is running....Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Client side:

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8887/Service/");

        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        ChannelFactory<IServiceContract> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceContract>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

        IServiceContract proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpointAddress);
        Console.WriteLine("Data received: " + proxy.GetData());
        Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
        Console.WriteLine("Data received after 10 seconds: " + proxy.GetData());
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.....");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Please note:

1. The receiveTimeout property set on server side is 5 seconds.
2. I'm waiting for 20 seconds in GetData() method on server side before returning the data.
3. I'm waiting for 10 seconds on client side before sending another request.

The application works fine without any exception. Ideally, in my opinion, it should throw an exception (as per my understanding from the definition of MSDN for receiveTimeout).

Thoughts anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[ReceiveTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding) – used by the Service Framework Layer to initialize the session-idle timeout which controls how long a session can be idle before timing out.

So, to get that behavior you have to use wsHttpBinding binding (it supports session) instead of basicHttpBinding (no session, hence receive no timeout).